# How to overwrite default value from properties of this object with call or apply method in JS

Tags: javascript, call, bind, apply

I've started learning call, apply and bind and now i want to use it but have some problems:

I have a function:

```
let addTableRow = function() {
    let template = HtmlTemplatesTelephony.ks.renderTableRow;
    this.id = "";
    this.creationDate = "";
    this.address = "";
    this.numberOfUser = "";
    this.accessExisting = true;
    $(DOM.tableBodyContainer).append(template(this));
};
```

I declared the this properties as default values

Here i invoke the function either with .call() or without:

```
let updateTable = function() {
    let locations = userData().locations;
    if(locations.length > 0) {
        for(let location of locations) {
            UIController.addLocation.call(location);
        }
    } else {
        UIController.addLocation();
    }
};
```

My idea was to use the 'this' values in the 'addTableRow' as default values in case of invoking the function without .call(). And when calling it with .call() I want to overwrite the 'this' default values. But exactly the opposite happens.

I know I could pass the object as parameter and set default object, but is there an other way to do it with .call()? Or is it the wrong use case for .call()?

Thanks for help!

*****  UPDATE  ******

Sorry, it is written in module pattern and i forgot to mention that the function 'addTableRow' is called 'addLoaction' in the return object. Here's some more code:

My UI controller:

```
let UIController = (function() {
let DOM = {
    tableHeadContainer: $('thead'),
    tableBodyContainer: $('tbody'),
    inputNumberLocations: $('#numberLocations'),
    inputAddress: $('.js-location-address'),
    inputUser: $('.js-location-user'),
    inputVpn: $('.js-location-vpn'),
    btnDeleteLocation: $('.js-delete-location'),
};


let addTableRow = function() {
    let template = HtmlTemplatesTelephony.ks.renderTableRow;
    this.id = "";
    this.creationDate = "";
    this.address = "";
    this.numberOfUser = "";
    this.accessExisting = true;
    $(DOM.tableBodyContainer).append(template(this));
};


return {
    getDOM: DOM,
    addLocation: addTableRow,
    removeLocation: removeTableRow

}
```

})();

And my main controller:

```
let Controller = (function(dataController, UIController) {

let updateTable = function() {
    let locations = userData().locations; // locations has the same properties as in function 'addTableTow'
    if(locations.length > 0) {
        for(let location of locations) {
            UIController.addLocation.call(location);
        }
    } else {
        UIController.addLocation();
    }
};

return {
    init: function() {
        setupEventListeners();
        updateTable();
    },
}
```

})(dataController, UIController);

I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Could you please specify, how and where `addTableRow` is invoked? Looking at `updateTable`, the `addTableRow` function isn't even mentioned which makes it really hard to see how your code works

Comment: thanks for your advice. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

When you `.call(obj)`, you are starting your function with `this` being equal to that object. When you say `this.id = ""`, you are *overriding* the `id` that you already had.

This may be a solution to your problem:

```
if (!this.id) {
  this.id = "";
}
if (!this.property) {
  this.property = "default";
}
// etc.
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. it's a good idea. I just improved it a bit to avoid checking each property. When I'm not using .call(newThis) my this refers to the owner, right? So i just ask `if(this.hasOwnProperty('addLocation')) {...`